# How to copy filtered data without copying empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

**Scenario**

I have an excel sheet with a lot of values. I am using some macro to filter those values.

**What I need**

I need to copy only the filtered values from current sheet to another sheet. I am doing the following way

```
Sub filterCopy()
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**Issue**

The above code doing exactly what is supposed to do by copying only the visible cells. But the problem is, it is copying entire sheet including all the blank cells upto row number 1048480 and even more. But my data is only upto row number 12. How should I copy only the visible cells that contains data and not all those blank cells?

**Pictures**

Filtered Sheet
[image]
After copied filtered data to another sheet
[image]

Comment: Would `Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets(2).Range("A1")` work for you? It would at least get rid of `.Select` which you should always [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: When use `A2:A`, it is only copy column A whereaby I need to copy all the filtered non empty cell. I use `Activesheet.UsedRange.Copy` and it seems working. But I am not sure if this will cause any other problems

Comment: Yes I overlooked that, see provided answer to tackle that problem.

Comment: @JvdV Thank you. Able to solve the issue as I stated in below comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't take into account the last cell in the vertical space, and actually copies everything in the A1 range.

The solution is first, to avoid Select as it provides low performance, then to use

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

to get the last row in the A column. This gives us

```
Sub filterCopy()
    Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets(2).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

To copy the full table with the filtered rows, then use

```
Sub filterCopy()
    Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets(2).Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: In fact I need not only A column, but also all filtered columns that contains value. Is there any issue in using `Activesheet.UsedRange.Copy`

Comment: @Anu See updated answer. `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` works on any range, so `Sheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` will work to copy the full table (but only the visible rows)

Comment: Thank you. By combining your and above person comment, I am able to do the job in one line as below
`Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets(2).Range("A1")`